# Закрасить угол у div в css с linear-gradient

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, не смог реализовать. Как закрасить угол с linear-gradient, чтобы было как в макете?

```css
.circle {
  position: absolute;
  width: 306px;
  height: 306px;
  right: -33%;
  top: -39%;
  background: #EBF4FB;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.div-1 {
  height: 301px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 26px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
  padding: 48px 31px;
  margin: 31px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-5 div-1">
      <div class="block circle"></div>
      <div class="col-xl"><img src="/img/tachometer.png" alt=""></div>
      <div class="col-xl text-div-1">Передать<br> показания счетчиков</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Такое можно изобразить относительно без костылей на одном лишь css - за счет `radial-gradient`

```css
.container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: radial-gradient(circle at 90% 0%, #ebf4fb, #ebf4fb 30%, #fff 30.1%);
    padding: 48px 31px;
    margin: 31px;
    box-shadow: 0px 5px 26px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.08);
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Для `div-1` пропишите `position: relative; overflow: hidden;` , а для блока `circle` `right: -103px;`

Comment: Получилось! Спасибо!

Comment: Одиночный минус бывает прилетает и просто так, это ещё не минусование.